# IS JSONP classified as AJAX?

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp, terminology

Is JSONP classfied as AJAX?

I am confused as i understood that the XHR is required to be used for the asynchronous communication but when i look at the jQuery code for JSONP it is "wrapped in an AJAX call

[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

if JSONP is not classified as AJAX then why have jQuery bundled it as an AJAX function or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd strictly say that [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) means "asynchronous communication between JavaScript and a Server using XML format", then only a few techniques called "Ajax" today would meet that definition, as even many "XML-HTTP-Requests" do not transport XML data.

So the JSONP technique is just one of the known asynchronous communication methods, and jQuery wanted to bundle all of them into one function - named with the most common term "ajax".

However, the term "ajax" is closely linked to the `XMLHTTPRequest` interface, which is limited by the same-origin-policy. While this one does not apply to JSONP, which uses `<script>` elements, JSONP is limited to GET-requests and needs a special serverside infrastructure.

Comment: thanks for the reply, makes things more clear

generally are JSONP solutions regarded as  a JSONP solution or  AJAX-JSONP solutions 

on a similar note, if an XHR returns HTML, then strictly speaking it is not XHR, correct?